# Change Item Name of Kendo PanelBar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I cannot change the name of the first item.
Using the below example works well on the second item and so on, but I cannot change the name of the first item, only subsequent items? How can I access the first item using jQuery.
Tried li:nth(0)

```
var li = panelbar.wrapper.find("> li:nth(1) span.k-link.k-header");
// Replace the content by "Title"
li.contents().first().replaceWith("Title");
```

You can see it here : http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/Uzugu

Answer (score 0):

For the first line use the first selector ":first"

```
var li = panelbar.wrapper.find("> li:first span.k-link.k-header");
// Replace the content by "Title"
li.contents().first().replaceWith("Title");
```

Comment: can I see some html, a little snippet perhaps?

Comment: I can change all elements apart from the top, tried this also   li = panelbar.wrapper.find("> li:nth-child(1) span.k-link.k-header");
                           li.contents().first().replaceWith("New Name");

Comment: var panelbar;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        panelbar = $("#panelbar").data("kendoPanelBar");
    });

Comment: Thank you, its very strange

Comment: try it this way: http://dojo.telerik.com/ecUvA, although your code looked fine to  me

Comment: Ok I worked out it is when I use   .Content(@<text>     </text>); what I place all my controls inside                                        @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
    .Name("panelbar")

         .Items(titles =>
         {
             titles.Add().Text("First Person")

               .Content(@<text>

                </text>);
             titles.Add().Text("Second Person");

             titles.Add().Text("Third Person");

         })

)